# Any idea on how to create a looped timed event in Libevent?

Tags: c++, network-programming, libevent

Ideally, I'd like to create an event to run every n minutes, to poll another server for an update on a condition.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could create the basic looping event with libevent 2.0.22 events, rather than using my own event loop?

Or am I misunderstanding the point of libevent?